# Opening cdf file from command line with arguments on windows

Tags: cdf-format, windows

I want to write a cdf file to read in the commmand line arguments and then do something with them.  Something like this:

```
Mathematica.exe 'filename.cdf' arguments
```

Then from inside the cdf call `$CommandLine` or something and then get those arguments.
Just wondering if this is possible.